# How to pass data from ViewModel to View code behind in Xamarin.Forms following MVVM?

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

So the question is pretty simple, I think:

I have a View and its associated ViewModel. ***I have a value generated in the ViewModel and want to pass it to the View's Code Behind***, following the MVVM pattern. I know it's entirely possible, because that's basically what's happening when using INotifyPropertyChanged and Data Binding, but I want to pass the value into a variable in the Code Behind, not a XAML component.

As an example, consider something like this:

> **ViewModel**
>
> > `public string VM_String { get; set; }`
>
> **View's Code Behind**
>
> > ```
> > ViewModel MyViewModel = new ViewModel;
> >
> > public string View_String { get; set; }
> > ```

I simply want to pass the value in VM_String onto View_String, **while following MVVM principles**, so something like:

> `View_String = MyViewModel.VM_String;`

is not what I want. I'd want those values decoupled from each other.

How would one go about doing this? Something to do with delegates / events maybe?

Thanks

Comment: What is this value in the code behind?? a control?? what is it??

Comment: It's just a variable that I declared in, say, the constructor. If I wanted to attach the value to a control I'd use data binding, which is not what I'm trying to do here.

Comment: Others way is using Xamarin.Essentials: Preferences https://stackoverflow.com/a/63553826/4654957

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create a [BindableProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties) in your view's code-behind and use xaml to bind this property to the property in your view model. Then you can use the propertyChanged event of BindableProperty to apply your logic whenever the binding value changes.

If your view is a ContentPage, [it's not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57201963/bindable-property-at-contentpage-level) to declare a BindableProperty in the code-behind and bind it in the xaml file of the same view. However, using an [attached BindableProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/attached-properties) will do the job.

In the code-behind of your view (NewPage.xaml.cs):

```
    public static readonly BindableProperty VMStringProperty 
        = BindableProperty.CreateAttached("VMString",
            typeof(string),
            typeof(NewPage),
            default(string),
            propertyChanged: VMStringChanged);

    public static string GetVMString(BindableObject target)
    {
        return (string)target.GetValue(VMStringProperty);
    }

    private static void VMStringChanged(BindableObject target, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var yourView = target as NewPage;
        var vmString = newValue as string; // or GetVMString(target)
        yourView.ApplyLogic(newValue); // ApplyLogic is an instance method in your NewPage class
    }
```

In the xaml file of your view (NewPage.xaml):

```
<ContentPage
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourNamespace"
    local:NewPage.VMString="{Binding VM_String}"
...
```

Using attached bindable properties this way is not a common thing to do. Instead, depending on your situation, you may consider creating a [custom control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/contentview) having the (non-attached) VmString bindable property in it. Then you can add this control like a normal control to your NewPage and bind its VmString property to the property in your page's ViewModel.

Comment: This sounds exactly like what I want. Would it be too much to ask for an example with a simple string, maybe? I'm checking your link but MSDN documentation always seems a bit too overwhelming to me. Thanks.

Comment: @Zidd What is the type of your view?

Comment: It's a regular XAML page, I guess. Something like "public partial class NewPage : ContentPage { }"

Comment: Thank you! Just one more question, how would I go about binding it also in the Code Behind instead of doing it in the XAML file?

Comment: @Zidd You can do: "this.SetBinding(VMStringProperty, "VM_String");" somewhere in you NewPage class. If this answer helped you solve your problem, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

The only way the code behind can interact with a View Model is through binding the View Model to the view.

So `ViewModel MyViewModel = new ViewModel;` this set up the view to know about the View Model.

```
VariableInCodeBehind = MyViewModel.VariableInViewModel;
```

This is the way you would assign a variable in the code behind with a variable from your View Model.

Comment: Well yes, but that's exactly what I'm trying to avoid here. I'm trying to find a roundabout way of doing this, as to decouple the View from the ViewModel. After all, isn't that the whole point of MVVM? Or am I getting this wrong?

Comment: Yes MVVM is a design pattern that states how you can architect your apps. This design patterns doesnt stop you from putting code in your code behind. There will be some use cases that will have you putting code in the Code Behind.

The take away is when using MVVM you have all your logic in a separate cs file that way you can unit test that easily. Unit testing a code behind is much more difficult.

The sweet spot is to put core logic (Commands etc) in your View Model but other things that dont require unit test can go in the View Model.

Comment: Interesting, hadn't thought about it from a unit testing perspective. I figured it was more about reusing the View with a different ViewModel, which is why I wanted to avoid referencing the current ViewModel directly. Thanks